# Using pry in a staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, staging, pry

My team has several staging servers that run against production data. I'm interested in using `pry` in a staging environment for better debugging.

Is there a tool for this? `pry-remote` looks like it might fit, but most people I've seen are using it locally with `pow` or `foreman` rather than against a remote server, so I'm not sure that's what its for. There's [an unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016019/creating-remote-drb-server-for-use-with-pry-remote) with this same idea.

If there wasn't a tool for this, I was thinking I might be able to just SSH into the server and run rails server, but I suspect that might interact weirdly with nginx or something, so I'd have to be more careful with this approach.

Comment: That question is pretty old. To my knowledge, I can't think of any reason stopping you from doing that. How about define pry gem within `group :development, :test, :staging do ...` Wouldn't that work the same as local machine when using SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some trouble getting pry-remote working, so I ended up sshing in and starting pry from there. The only things I needed to do were 1) learn to start unicorn (we use a different server when developing locally) 2) prevent timeouts on unicorn + nginx. Thanks to @BillyChan for first recommending this.